# Capacitor selection from Linear Technology generated design

Tags: capacitor

I'll preface this by saying I'm a SW Engineer. I've used the Linear Technologies Software to design a step down DC power supply from 12V to 6V. The package has given me a design but I'm a tad confused by the output capacitors given by the design.

The first output cap is a ceramic but is illustrated on the design as polarised. I thought ceramic caps weren't bothered with positive and negative connections. On top of that the spec for the cap is 10uF, ESR = 5M, and ESL = 0.3nH.

The second "Output Bulk Cap" is polarised, but I assume it can be electrolytic, and has values of 100uF, ESR = 15M and ESL = 1nH.

I normally do my shopping at Farnell's UK site and can't figure out what I need as there's nothing that comes close to 5 Mega Ohm ESR. Am I looking for a special type of cap which I'm not familiar with? I'd be very grateful for any pointers.

EDIT - this is the circuit: -

[image]

Comment: As a note, series inductances are generally very slow for these components (i.e. 300 pH as shown); you need to be more concerned about the stray inductance in your traces. ESR means `Equivalent Series Resistance`, which, along with inductance, is a non-ideal characteristic due to subsequent power losses. Such devices known as `super capacitors` have ultra-low ESR values.

Answer (score 7):

It means 5 milli-ohm not mega-ohm. Imagine the capacitor part were shorted out. You'd be left with a resistor, the effective series resistor. If that we're 5 mega ohm then it's a nonsense value even for the lightest of loads on the output. Here's the equivalent circuits for capacitors, inductors and resistors. Sometimes they are shown differently but these are generally the most applicable to common circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsZ847.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you are able to show the schematic, I might be able to recommend options.

Comment: Andy, L2 comes from the wire of course, but why is there a C2 for the inductor/resistor model? Does this is anyway have to do with the contacts? If yes, how so?

Comment: @sherrellbc an inductor has a self resonant frequency due to the proximity of the coils with each other - the capacitance is anything from 1pF to several tens of pF (typically in that range for small inductors in the tens of nH to tens of uH). For an 0805 resistor, self capacitance might be around 0.1pF.

Comment: Oops so used to Mega Ohms as opposed to milli. Hope this link works [link](http://s1289.photobucket.com/user/johnfwhitmore/media/Misc/LTC3603_schematic_zpsdc61e5f6.png.html)

Comment: [schematic](http://s1289.photobucket.com/user/johnfwhitmore/media/Misc/LTC3603_schematic_zpsdc61e5f6.png.html)

Comment: @jwhitmore I've added the picture to your question so that folk can review it and make recommendations. Bad lad for thinking Mega ohms hehehe!!!

Comment: @Andy, so the self resonating property then is modeled by the parallel capacitor? That is, magnetic field and electric field oscillate?

Comment: @sherrellbc parallel resonant circuit I would prefer to say

Comment: @sherrellbc - yes and no. Any physical conductor has both inductance and capacitance. You get a magnetic field any time you move charge, and inductance describes how easy it is to change the strength of the field. Likewise, wherever you have a potential difference (and a non-superconductor always does between the ends - that's Ohm's Law), and the capacitance value describes, roughly, how much energy is stored in the electric field. The resonant frequency of a component is just the frequency at which the inductive and capacitive impedances are equal.

Comment: @sherrellbc a 1 mm diameter, 10 mm long wire has an inductance (in free space) of 5nH approximately. A 2 mm track on a PCB that is 10 mm long above an earth plane that is 1 mm distant has a capacitance of 1pF. These may seem like low figures but at 1GHz and above they become significant.

Comment: May I ask another question about the generated circuit. In the schematic output there is not value for Cfilt. Can I assume that this implies that it's an open circuit.

Comment: @jwhitmore Definitely open circuit. Normally there is no capacitor and quite often there is the Cff cap but very infrequently I see Cfilt.

Comment: If you are done with this question please select an answer to formally accept @jwhitmore.